# Looking for soil shapefiles for India

Tags: data

Is there any place where we can get soil Shapefiles of India (if not detailed information, can we get region wise/state wise)?
I  have seen this data base for few regions like USA.

To compute "Q" in a basin or at a point, I am looking for soil shapefiles to use in Arcgis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>As far as I am aware, this data is currently not available freely due to various reasons.</strike>

*update*
You can download the shapefile from FAO's Site:
http://www.fao.org/geonetwork/srv/en/main.home?uuid=446ed430-8383-11db-b9b2-000d939bc5d8

---

*Original Answer*

However you can get some basic information about the various soil properties for a given area here : [India-WRIS](http://india-wris.nrsc.gov.in/soilapp.html)

You can also find some old maps at [EU Soils](http://eusoils.jrc.ec.europa.eu/esdb_archive/EuDASM/Asia/lists/cin.htm), which you could digitize to create new shapefiles.

Disclaimer: I am currently working on the team that is involved in the development of the first linked site

Comment: Thanks for the information. I got soil details of the India area in pdf format. There is huge area to digitize and I am avoiding digitization option. I am looking for shape files so that I can use it to get results of the application. The site you provided also having lot of useful information.

Comment: A co-worker just pointed out this link on FAO's site: http://www.fao.org/geonetwork/srv/en/main.home?uuid=446ed430-8383-11db-b9b2-000d939bc5d8

Answer (score 0):

You can download detailed geology of India once you have registered, which is free, from here: http://bhukosh.gsi.gov.in/Bhukosh/Public.